# Select custom directive and ng-change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using `<select>` with a custom directive, I want to run a function when the value is changed.

html

```
<select name="user_type" ng-model="user_type" user-type ng-change="check_type()">
```

directive

```
gb_dash.directive('userType', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^ngModel',
        scope:{
            check_type: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            scope.check_type = function(){
                console.log('changed');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have an isolate scope, your `check_type` is not in the same scope as the `ng-change` expression. And you wouldn't want it to be so.

Instead, `ng-model` provides a way to register a listener with `ngModel.$viewChangeListeners` - which is exactly what `ngChange` directive uses - to hook into view model change events.

```
require: "ngModel",
scope: { }, // to mimic your directive - doesn't have to be isolate scope
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
   ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(function(){
     console.log('changed');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of your isolate scope, you can include a call to `$parent` to achieve your result. Try this change...

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.$parent.check_type = function() {
        console.log('changed');
    }
}
```

However, calling `$parent` may not be ideal for your situation.

Alternatively you can ditch `ng-change` and instead `$watch` your `ngModel`. This could be accomplished as such...

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    scope.$watch(function() {
        return ngModel.$modelValue;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('model value changed...', newValue, oldValue);
    }, true);
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8nogwf8h/) - `$parent` demo

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/epLb4emc/) - `$watch` demo

Comment: +1 Your scope.$parent makes me curious to try it out on the directive I'm customizing and invoking the ngChange. Now I need to learn what is isolate scope and why straight scope.$eval doesn't work on isolate scope. This works now:

`link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

 scope.doChange = function() {
  ngModel.$setDirty();
  scope.$parent.$eval(attrs.ngChange);
 };`